# How To get Accurate current location in ios swift 5 meters accurate

Tags: ios, swift, location

i want accurate current location , i got current location 100 meters aways from my current location

this is my code if you know any way to get pin point accuracy

```
 let manager = CLLocationManager()
      manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
      manager.delegate = self
      manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
      manager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
      manager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = false
```

Comment: There is no such thing as pin point accuracy when dealing with GPS you can change from best for navigation to best and get better accuracy but if I remember correctly there is a 30 ft accuracy range but of course it depends on the skies and anything in between the device and satellite.

Comment: so there is no way ? , because i am doing all stuff in 20 meters range

Comment: Best and nearest ten meters accuracy types should in theory give you better than 20 meters but that is only if it is available in the area and the connection between the device and satellite are optimal.

Comment: If you find the video for Apple release where the ultra was announced they talk about newer technology that will eventually come to all devices but as of now only the ultra uses the new tech.

Answer (score 0):

The accuracy of Location depends on:

- GPS device (or hardware, or even firmware)
- GPS device maximum accuracy support
- Quality of connection between your GPS device and Satellite

  - This can be affected by obstacles (metal objects, tall buildings,...)
- Your phone/watch/pad power level (system can reduce the accuracy to save battery)
- User may only allow your app to access reduced accuracy or not precise location
- Your setting of LocationManager:

  - `manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation`
  - This setting will also turn on Sensor to improve the accuracy of location.

I am working on a Workout project also, already saw a lot of Location point that has hozirontalAccuracy below 5 meters.
And, we just hope that the user's GPS signal is strong and stable, there is no other method to improve now.